# How to access underlying class attributes in a selectedListBoxItem in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a `ListPicker (items=Week1,Week2)` that allows me to toggle between 2 lists in another `ListBox`:

```
< toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="LP1"
                     Margin="12,8,12,0"
                     Grid.Row="1" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Top"
                     SelectedIndex="1"
                     SelectionChanged="WeekSelectionChanged"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding WeekSelection}" />
```

The logic for the `WeekSelectionChanged` method in `ListPicker` is simple:

```
if(this.LP1.SelectedIndex == 0) 
    this.ListBox1.ItemsSource = Week1; 
else if (this.LP1.SelectedIndex == 1) 
    this.ListBox1.ItemsSource = Week2;
```

The Lists are composed as such (repeat for Week2 list):

```
ObservableCollection<TB> Week1 = new ObservableCollection<TB>(); 
Week1.Add(new TB() { F_Name = "Day 1", F_Color = "Yellow" }); 
Week1.Add(new TB() { F_Name = "Day 2", F_Color = "Yellow" }); 
this.ListBox1.ItemsSource = Week1;
```

The class TB is:

```
public class TB 
{
    public string F_Name { get; set; }
    public string F_Color { get; set; }     
}
```

When I "long press" a list item, the foreground color changes to Gray. But when I toggle between lists, the change does not "save", and the original Yellow is displayed. I want to keep these changes by changing the `F_Color` value of the particular list item selected.

How can I access the underlying `TB` class and its attributes?

Answer (score 0):

You must subscribe to the SelectionChanged event of the list control either in code-behind or via the events panel in either visual studio or Blend.
In the handler for this event, you will cast the selected item to its actual type: TB.
Then you can read/write its properties and should see the change reflected in the list item.
Something like this:

```
namespace PhoneApp1
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        ListBox mylistbox;
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // here, for illustration purposes,  I have declared and instantiated a listbox in the code-behind, 
            // normally the declaration and initialization is done by auto-generated code, 
            // when you have dropped the list into your GUI via the designer...
            // although the actual adding of items is either populated in code-behind 
            // or is accomplished by binding to a source in the designer.
            this.mylistbox = new ListBox();

            // add some items...
            TB[] tbs = new TB[] { new TB(), new TB(), new TB() };
            this.mylistbox.ItemsSource = tbs;

            // subscribe to the SelectionChanged event...
            this.mylistbox.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(mylistbox_SelectionChanged);
        }

        // respond to the SelectionChanged event...
        void mylistbox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TB tb = this.mylistbox.SelectedItem as TB;
            if (tb == null) { return; }

            // the 'as' operator allows for a safe way of testing what we are using before we use it...
            // we passed the validation, so now we can do what we like with the type...
            // the selected TB item is being operated upon here, but that does not stop it from being an item in the list.
            // this means whatever we 'do' to it here, is actually 'doing' it to the selected item in the list.
            tb.F_Color = "Yellow";
        }
    }

    public class TB
    {
        public string F_Name { get; set; }
        public string F_Color { get; set; }
    }  

}
```

**EDIT:**
Here is a revision of the above code, tailored for the fact that the selected item becomes null when the "Hold" event is fired:

```
namespace PhoneApp1
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private TB currentItem;

    ListBox mylistbox;

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // here, for illustration purposes,  I have declared and instantiated a listbox in the code-behind, 
        // normally the declaration and initialization is done by auto-generated code, 
        // when you have dropped the list into your GUI via the designer...
        // although the actual adding of items is either populated in code-behind 
        // or is accomplished by binding to a source in the designer.
        this.mylistbox = new ListBox();

        this.currentItem = null;

        // add some items...
        TB[] tbs = new TB[] { new TB(), new TB(), new TB() };
        this.mylistbox.ItemsSource = tbs;

        // subscribe to the SelectionChanged event...
        this.mylistbox.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(mylistbox_SelectionChanged);

        this.mylistbox.Hold += new EventHandler<GestureEventArgs>(mylistbox_Hold);
    }

    void mylistbox_Hold(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.currentItem == null) { return; }
        this.currentItem.F_Color = "Yellow";
    }

    // respond to the SelectionChanged event...
    void mylistbox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.currentItem = ((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem as TB;;
    }
}

public class TB
{
    public string F_Name { get; set; }
    public string F_Color { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: This won't work because technically, on a Long Hold event, the "SelectedItem" is null, and thus tb is null. As a result, I was forced to do this: ListBoxItem selectedListBoxItem = this.ListBox1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem((sender as MenuItem).DataContext) as ListBoxItem;  but then I can't access F_Color.

Comment: I should also mention that I am using a Context Menu that pops up after a long hold.

Comment: Perhaps you can store the selected item in a private class-level variable in the SelectionChanged handler instead...so you have a reference to the one the long hold was done on when you need to use it...at first...before the hold, there is a SelectionChanged event fired off because of the initial "press" on the list item...use this to "remember" at any given time, which as the most recently pressed item, which is always the one the long hold was done on when you are in the long-hold handler...then operate upon this referenced item as needed..?